# Could not connect to Twilio: Signaling connection error

Tags: google-chrome, browser, twilio, compatibility, twilio-php

I am trying to make the connection between chrome (v - 67) and chrome (v- 79), at the time got the error like:

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://global.vss.twilio.com/signaling' failed: Error in connection establishment: net:: ERR_SOCKS_CONNECTION_FAILED`

I have attached the video link here. please check out and let me help out for this.

Chrome (v-79) : connection is successfully. 
check below url- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aVsRhDEmp7q1atAwMcbh9L_bPv-iiqNA/view

Chrome(v-67): Could not connect to Twilio: Signaling connection error
check URL: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TbGaJ_aSyfswTGOXA-8Sw1u_s_skBH-C/view

I have added below option in `connectOptions`

`const connectOptions = {
  _useTwilioConnection: true
};`

But I have faced the same issue. I have created an Http tunnel. So, If you want to check this feature using my end. 
please hit this link: https://b256e195.ngrok.io  
**Code to reproduce the issue:**

```js
Video.connect(data.token, connectOptions).then(roomJoined, function (error) {
      alert("Video connect error part");
      console.log(error);
      log('Could not connect to Twilio: ' + error.message);
    });
```

**Expected behavior:**

I need to work on both sides.

**Actual behavior:**

The connection could not establish in chrome (v-67)

**Software versions:**

- [x] Browser(s): Chrome(v-79), Chrome(v-67) (not working), Chrome(v-75) (not working)
- [x] Operating System: window 10
- [x] twilio-video.js: we have migrate from 1.x to 2.x
- [x] Third-party libraries (e.g., Angular, React, etc.): Angular js